# .Net Core2.2 : how to change characterset in EF codefirst approach

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I have tried using `Charset=utf8;` in the connection string and using `[MySqlCharset("utf8")]` in my model(which was not recognized by VsCode).
I have also read about this method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<ComplexKey>(e =>
    {
      e.HasKey(p => new { p.Key1, p.Key2 });
      e.ForMySQLHasCollation("utf8"); // defining collation at Entity level
      e.Property(p => p.Key1).ForMySQLHasCharset("utf8"); // defining charset in a property
      e.Property(p => p.CollationColumnFA).ForMySQLHasCollation("utf8"); // defining collation in a property
    });
  }
```

but I have not tested it because I think it is tedious to do that for every single table and there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the charset inside your connection string to MySql ( in your database context class ), and then you will not need to declare the charset on any property.

Example:

```
public  class YourDbContext : DbContext {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        // See the charset in the end of this string.
        private string _yourConnectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword; CharSet=utf8;";

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder) {
            builder.UseMySQL( _yourConnectionString  );
        }
}
```